# Detect scroll on tbody in vue

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I have a table with a `sticky` header and scrollable `tbody` but I can't get my '`scroll` or 'window.addEventListener('scroll')' to work at all. How do you detect a scroll in a `table` `body` only?

```
created() {
    window.addEventListener('scroll', this.handleScroll);
},

destroyed() {
    window.removeEventListener('scroll', this.handleScroll);
},

methods: {
    handleScroll() {
        console.log('scrolled)
    },
}
```

I have tried adding `v-scroll="handleScroll"` to `table` & `tbody` but still doesn't call it even when I place mouse inside the `table` and `scroll`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Added `@scroll` to my `<div class="table-responsive" @scroll='handleScroll'>` which worked

Answer (score 0):

Add the event Listener to the table element. If this doesn't work, try to add the event listener to the `tbody`

```
<table @scroll="handleScroll">
  <!-- ... -->
</table>
```

Comment: As per my description, it doesn't work. I already tried that as i put

Answer (score 0):

You can use `v-on:scroll.passive` listener. Here is an example:

```js
new Vue({
     el: '#app',
     methods:{
          handleScroll(e){
               console.log("scroll");
          }
     }
})
```

```css
table {
    width: 100%;
}

thead, tbody, tr, td, th { display: block; }

tr:after {
    content: ' ';
    display: block;
    visibility: hidden;
    clear: both;
}

thead th {
    height: 30px;

    /*text-align: left;*/
}

tbody {
    height: 80px;
    overflow-y: auto;
}

tbody td, thead th {
    width: 19.2%;
    float: left;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue/dist/vue.min.js"></script>

<div id="app">
    <table>
         <thead>
              <tr>
                   <th>Month</th>
                   <th>Savings</th>
              </tr>
         </thead>
         <tbody v-on:scroll.passive='handleScroll'>
              <tr>
                   <td>January</td>
                   <td>$100</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                   <td>February</td>
                   <td>$80</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                   <td>March</td>
                   <td>$90</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                   <td>April</td>
                   <td>$190</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                   <td>May</td>
                   <td>$80</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                   <td>June</td>
                   <td>$30</td>
              </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

Comment: I tried your solution and it still does not fire. No idea why not but I have now included my full `HTML`